# utf8 console.log output using node.js

Tags: node.js, utf-8, cmd

I have utf8 information coming for a mysql database.
I want to use console.log to output it to the console.

but it shows "box" characters instead of the utf8 data.

Where am I loosing the data ? and what should I do to fix this ?
is the problem when reading the data from the DB ? (using felixge-node-mysql-v0.9.5-1)
or during output to the console? (using console.log)
ot maybe its the console itself (windows command window set to font "Lucida Console")

Thanks.

UPDATE:
I now believe its an issue with the fonts of the windows command window.
when I run the same node script using a powershell window 
I do see different chars that don't look like what I expect.
whoever, when I Try to paste then into this browser window they suddenly change to the right font and chars.

Comment: Sounds like either your terminal(s) use fonts that don't contain glyphs for the characters you're printing, or they are set to an encoding other than UTF8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I would still love a better solution what I have found for now is the following solution that works for me:

I will use Windows PowerShell ISE.
Inside it I ran the following command:
`chcp 65001`

running node.exe my.js from the lowest pane in WPSISE results in the exact printout I wanted in the middle pane.

Another point to mention is that if I try to open a cmd.exe window and run `chcp 65001` in it and then execute my script I get 
`node.js:284 throw new Error('process.stdout cannot be closed');`

Comment: in my case instead of box, the thin space (\u200B) is actually outputted as Γò¼├┤Γö£├ºΓö£┬╗ (on console & file redirection both) and the solution didn't worked. Did you ran into any such scenario ?